# Internet stops working when using static IP

Tags: networking, windows-8, home-networking, static-ip

I am running windows 8.1 and I am trying to configure a static IP address for server hosting. Without using a static IP address, my IPV4 properties are these:

[image]

And the internet and web work fine. However, when I try to set up a static IP as so:

[image]

My internet does this:

[image]

And gives [this warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWfDG.jpg) about multiple Default Gateways.

The result of ipconfig/all is:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600] (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\Phoenix>ipconfig/all
>
> Windows IP Configuration
>
> Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Caroline    Primary Dns Suffix 
>   . . . . . . . :    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid    IP
>   Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . .
>   . : No
>
> Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
>   . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter    Physical Address. . . .
>   . . . . . : AE-22-0B-BE-B0-3C    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Yes    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>
> Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . .
>   . . . : ASUS PCE-AC68 802.11ac Network Adapter    Physical Address. .
>   . . . . . . . : AC-22-0B-BE-B0-3C    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . .
>   : Yes    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    Link-local IPv6
>   Address . . . . . : fe80::9573:d94:99d4:acd9%4(Preferred)    IPv4
>   Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2(Preferred)    Subnet Mask .
>   . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . .
>   . : Thursday, July 21, 2016 1:57:39 PM    Lease Expires . . . . . . .
>   . . . : Friday, July 22, 2016 1:57:38 PM    Default Gateway . . . . .
>   . . . . : 192.168.1.1    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   192.168.1.1    DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 128721419    DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-90-9F-4F-38-2C-4A-B2-B6-3B
>
> DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8    NetBIOS over Tcpip.
>   . . . . . . . : Enabled
>
> Ethernet adapter Hamachi:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . .
>   . . . : LogMeIn Hamachi Virtual Ethernet Adapter    Physical Address.
>   . . . . . . . . : 7A-79-19-14-B7-AB    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . .
>   . : Yes    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    IPv6 Address. .
>   . . . . . . . . . : 2620:9b::1914:b7ab(Preferred)    Link-local IPv6
>   Address . . . . . : fe80::791b:4133:574d:8ae7%10(Preferred)    IPv4
>   Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 25.20.183.171(Preferred)    Subnet Mask
>   . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . .
>   : Thursday, July 21, 2016 1:52:25 PM    Lease Expires . . . . . . . .
>   . . : Friday, July 21, 2017 1:52:24 PM    Default Gateway . . . . . .
>   . . . : 2620:9b::1900:1
>                                          25.0.0.1    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 25.0.0.1    DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   184701170    DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . :
>   00-01-00-01-1C-90-9F-4F-38-2C-4A-B2-B6-3B
>
> DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
>                                          fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
>                                          fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
>
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{CFB2AF4B-309A-433C-806C-6E35B6ECC8AF}:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
>   . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
>   00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
>   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>
> Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . .
>   . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface    Physical Address. . . . .
>   . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . .
>   : No    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    IPv6 Address. . . .
>   . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:43d:3527:3f57:fefd(Prefe rred)
>   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . :
>   fe80::43d:3527:3f57:fefd%7(Preferred)    Default Gateway . . . . . . .
>   . . :    DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 318767104    DHCPv6
>   Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-90-9F-4F-38-2C-4A-B2-B6-3B
>
> NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
>
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{C61B7E6E-CCE5-4B38-987F-9EF19A3AEA1E}:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
>   . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
>   00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
>   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

The result of route print is:
[image]

The weirdest part of this (to me) is that this was working before, but stopped working when microsoft forcibly installed an update, and has stopped working several times in the past upon microsoft installing an update. Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: Are you running on wireless?  Run Ipconfig when you have it Auto Assign and give us the IPv4 address listed there.

Comment: Yes, wireless. The ipconfig pasted above is with auto assign. It says it's assigned to "192.168.1.2 (preferred)" even though I haven't set any preferred ip.

Comment: Can you ping 192.168.1.1 when the Internet is working? Can you ping 192.168.1.1 when the Internet is not working? You need to do some troubleshooting and figure out what's different between these two cases.

Comment: Oh, I assumed that was with the static IP.  What does Ipconfig/all return for the wireless NIC when you have it statically set?

Comment: Here is the ping with and then without the internet working: http://imgur.com/a/NfzIM Here is the ipconfig without the internet working http://imgur.com/a/O0JnB

Comment: When you set your manual IP, try setting the DNS server to obtain automatically.

Comment: Windows does not allow me to select that option unless I'm also obtaining the IP automatically.

Comment: Try the command `netsh winsock reset` then you may have to restart your PC

Comment: I tried netsh winsock reset and restarted, it behaves the same way.

Comment: Is there any other devices on your network using the .11 IP address?

Comment: You could also try ipconfig /flushdns.

Comment: No other devices by the .11 address. I tried using the .42 IP address, it did the same thing.

Comment: Ok, can you add the output of `route print` onto your post?

Comment: Also, which Windows update is breaking this? Do you know exactly which one it is? You could also try updating the network adapter driver.

Comment: I added the result of route print. It  also might be worth mentioning that when I try to configure the static IP windows gives me this warning: http://imgur.com/a/sdmt6 . I don't know what update it was, windows told me it was installing an update and restarting my computer in 15 minutes.

Comment: That warning is SUPER helpful, this is a Default Gateway conflict.  I'm guessing your Hamachi Ethernet adapter is messing with this.  Try disabling that then setting the static IP.  ALWAYS post warning messages you've received when asking a question.

Comment: Oh damn! That worked! If you post that as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Also worth noting that your Ethernet adapter has an address in a HUGE public IP address range (25.0.0.0/8). Any website which exists in that range, your PC will think that it can reach it directly. Requests to websites in that range will fail. You should be using [RFC 1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918) ranges on Internal Networks.

Comment: Agreed @Cand3r, that warning should have been posted with the original question. That's literally the most essential part lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posted in the comments, the computer was giving a Default Gateway conflict warning.  This is where the computer is looking to get out to the internet.  The Hamachi network is conflicting with the internal network.  Disable this network then set the static IP.